# Can we specify download location for anchor tag?

Tags: html

I am using anchor tag in my html code to provide download option. But, is it possible to provide default download location in html code?

Sample html code:

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" target="_blank" download>
   <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

Comment: you mean where should the file be stored ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

It wouldn't typically be useful: Under normal circumstances, the author of a website doesn't have any idea what directories exist on the visitor's computer.

(The `download` attribute allows you to suggest a *filename*, but not a location).

Comment: Hey guys, the download="filename.csv" works perfectly fine for me in all browsers except IE. Is there any specific way/alternative we can do for IE, any idea? I have a similar case where I need to download as csv.